# Magento if product name contains statement

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

I have set up a complex magneto order email which sends estimated delivery dates to customers when they checkout. However for a specific product category I do not want to echo the estimated delivery date.

I am wondering the best method to do this...

MY first thought was to get category Id from product Id, and then do an if statement to say if category = A do not show code else show code.

I tried using this

```
$ordered_items = $_order->getAllItems(); 
Foreach($ordered_items as $item){     
$itemId = $item->getItemId(); 
$itemsku = $item->getSku(); 
$catId = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();         
} ?>
```

But this just returned "Array" when i try and echo the $catId.

My other thought was to get the product name, and say something like if name contains('sometext'), execute.

1) How do I correctly get the category ID of a product that lies in a single category.

2) How do I do an if statement to say "if product name contains ('sometext')"

Regards, Frank

Comment: `Array` is being returned because you're trying to `echo` an array. The `$catId` variable is an array (notice that the name of the function is plural,  `getCategoryIds`). Try `print_r()` to debug the structure of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product can belong to many categories, that's why you are getting an array instead of single id. You can add following after your code to check for the category you are interested in. Do note that if you have same type of category names then it is more wise to check with id.

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                 ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
                 ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catId)
                 ->addIsActiveFilter();

foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
    if(strpos($cat->getName(), "your_sometext") !== false){                 
        echo 'your category was in the product';
    }
    // or
    if($cat->getId() == 100){                 
        echo 'your category was in the product';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, some good information here. How do I get the single category ID of the ordered product?